# Is it possible to install a LAN-socket into this empty one?

Tags: receptacle, cables, socket, internet

Our router in our appartment is plugged into from what i've gathered a [telephone line socket](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichle-Stecker) in the living room. The same telephone line socket can be found in two other rooms, where about 10-15 years ago they were used to plug in a telephone.

Because there never has been a use for a telephone in my current room, the respective socket has never been installed. Because of this I currently have a unfinished socket in my room with a lid on it. If you open the lid you can see a cable which just kind runs through were the socket is.

Now to my actual question:
Assuming that internet is running through this cable, would it be possible to directly install a LAN socket instead of a telephone line socket, if so would I with relatively small knowledge be able to do this myself or should I hire a professional for this?[image]

Comment: Not really clear what you have now. **A picture would help a lot**. Do you currently have: Router plugged into a telephone jack? Router with a wire snaking through a hole in the wall but without a jack? Something else?

Comment: The router is currently plugged in the socket from the picture, but with an adapter from TT38 to RJ11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### tldr: NO

You might even have Cat5 or Cat5e cable here (common to use them for telephone once they became widespread.) The problem is that telephone wiring is commonly daisy-chained, which will not work for ethernet, and that the signal on the telephone line (a single pair of the 4 pairs in Cat5/5e/6/6a) requires the modem part of the router before it becomes ethernet. So tapping into the phone line carrying (Probably ADSL) to your router will more likely break your internet than connect you to it.

Answer (score 1):

POTS (*plain old telephone service*) commonly used four-conductor cabling and is limited to low frequencies. Though you could use it for a [DSL connection](https://www.blog.skywaywest.com/2011/12/what-is-a-dsl-splitter-and-what-does-it-do/), that requires special hardware at each end of the wires.

If you can snake wires through the wall, you'd be better served (no pun intended) by replacing the POTS cable with [Cat 5e or faster Ethernet cable](https://www.tripplite.com/products/ethernet-cable-types). Then use inexpensive Ethernet wall plates at each end. You *might* try tying some strong nylon cord to the existing cable, and pulling the old cable from another outlet... but many POTS installations used solid copper wires, which won't pull easily around bends.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation...i replaced literally all coaxial and phone cables with Cat 7. Most probably your phone cable is not LAN compatible - it should have 4 pairs of wires and optionally, a shield.
To be honest, it's not a space science, just some crimping tools, a cable and a special cable lubricant to pull/insert the cable. Internet is full of tutorials

Comment: Wow. CAT7 is exceedingly expensive and only useful for 10Gb/s with proper NICs & routers. If you've got the proper hardware at the ends, enjoy your massively fast network!

Comment: @FreeMan, thx. TBH, currently I benefit mostly from the PoE capabilities ... but since I'm changing the infra ... I decided to do it in future proof way. Fibre optics are getting popular, but even if my internet is SIM based ... 5G also delivers good rates